# XML-schema version 1.1 to Java-classes using xjc.exe

Tags: xsd, xjc

I am having trouble converting xsd-files to java-classes using the xjc command with XML version 1.1. I believe it is a known problem that xjc.exe and XML 1.1 are not very friendly towards each other. If there is no viable solution using xjc and XML-schema 1.1 then is there any similar solution for converting XML-schema 1.1?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Exactly what kind of 'trouble' are you having?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see JAXB does not support Schema 1.1 see this open issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-994

(Sorry for waking an old question)